# Why can't I code an EKEvent title?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calendar, title

I am using the following code to create an event within the iPhone's calendar;

```
        EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title     = @"DHSB Assignment: %@", Assignment1.text;

        event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

        [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err;
        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 
        [EKEventStore release];

        NSLog(@"Successfully added '%@' to the calendar", Assignment1.text);
```

Why is this saving an event with the name "DHSB Assignment: %@" rather than "DHSB Assignment: Example Text"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DHSB Assignment: %@", Assignment1.text];
```

Your current code is equivalent to

```
[event setTitle:@"DHSB Assignment: %@"];
[Assignment1 text];
```

…which is valid, so it compiles and runs fine even though it isn’t doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks, its pretty logic to use this property but I was looking myself as this property is not in the Class Reference